# How can I prove sum of the squares of the roots of $x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ is equal to $a^2-2b$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, cubics, symmetric-polynomials

How would I prove that the sum of the squares of the roots of $x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ is equal to $a^2-2b$?

Comment: Do you know how to express the coefficients in terms of the roots. If not you can look it up. It should help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas should be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

Say the roots are $r,s,t$.  Then $$(x-s)(x-r)(x-t)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$$

Comparing coefficients we see that $$s+r+t=-a\quad \& \quad sr+st+rt=b$$

It follows that $$a^2=(s+r+t)^2=s^2+r^2+t^2+2(sr+st+rt)$$  and we are done.